Nemos "Open as root" is not working: "Access was denied" w/o showing the credentials input
I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 24.10 and replaced Nautilus with Nemo. However, Nemo's "Open as root" from the context menu does not work as usual. It gives me the following error:

Could not display "admin:///home/mike". Access was denied."


It doesn't show me the usual "root credential input box" (not sure what the official name is) at all and it doesn't make a difference from which directory I'm calling the action.
Opening Nemo in elevated mode from the terminal using sudo nemo e.g. when inside /home/mike does work as expected.
